Velocity of Wilson fermions
Consider a LFT of Wilson fermions given by $$H=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi}\psi_k^\dagger\left(-\frac{\sin(ka)}{a}\gamma^0\gamma^1+\left(m+\frac{1-\cos(k a)}{a}\right)\gamma^0\right)\psi_k.$$
For given $m$ and $k$, the energy of electrons and positrons is given by $$E(k)=\sqrt{\left(m+\frac{1-\cos(k)}{a}\right)^2+\frac{\sin(ka)}{a}^2}.$$
The velocity of that electron is given by the group velocity
$$v_g=\frac{\partial E(k)}{\partial k}=\frac{(1+ma)\sin(ka)}{\sqrt{2+ma(2+ma)-2(1+ma)\cos(ka)}}.$$
Now, when evaluating this velocity in the large mass limit, $m\rightarrow\infty$, I get $$\lim_{m\to\infty}v_g=a\sin(ka),$$
which is non-vanishing. I know that in the continuum limit $a\to0$ and this model yields the correct prediction in the continuum: electrons with inifinite mass shall not move. However, if one takes this model as it is and is interested in its features regardless of the continuum limit, what is the interpretation of excitations with infinity mass which nevertheless have a finite velocity?
